# Can netty codec send package while object serialization

Tags: java, netty

suppose I want to use netty 4.X to transfer big java object (with many container). I want to use a ByteBuf as buffer during encoder in order to optimize performance and minimize memory usage, so I have two questions before I proceed.

1- I want to use MessageToByteEncoder to complete this job, is it suitable?

2- Can we writeAndFlush ByteBuf to ChannelHandlerContext when ever buffer's capacity is reached inside encod(ChannelHandlerContext, Object, ByteBuf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it looks like you would want to use `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdaptor` and just allocate the ByteBuf by yourself in `write(...)` and the call `ctx.write(...)` whenever you filled the buffer.